# Asp.Net Boilerplate, How to apply queries on database tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate

I am using Asp.Net boilerplate framework, I created a table in database by Code-First approach. Now i want to get Records from that table but applying query like this returning empty data. Why?

```
 MyAppDbContext db = new MyAppDbContext();
 var list = db.NewTables.ToList();
```

But List is returned as empty while table contains data actually.

Answer (score 3):

Inject `IRepository` instead of using `DbContext` directly:

```
public class TaskManager : DomainService, ITaskManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<Task, long> _taskRepository;

    public TaskManager(IRepository<Task, long> taskRepository)
    {
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    public void GetTasks()
    {
        var tasks = _taskRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

Read more in ABP documentation:

- Repositories: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories
- Domain Services: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Domain-Services